# How to setup git for RStudio projects on shared Windows folders

Tags: git

I have all my RStudio projects in a shared Windows folder, say `//server/share`. I can successfully create a project at `//server/share/project`, and when I do so in an empty folder RStudio populates the working directory like this:

[image]

Note that because I've checked the option to create a local Git repository for the project, **the project folder should have an extra file called `.gitignore`**. Moreover, the "Git" tab in RStudio, which should look like this

[image]

actually looks like this, as if the Git folder was `C:/Windows`:

[image]

I understand RStudio's implementation of Git is still in its early stages (RStudio itself is yet to reach version 1), so I guess the workaround to this problem revolves using the Shell, but I have no idea how to make it work. I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i got the error today. Here is my successful workaround

Map your //server/share to a drive, say U: (using Map network drive)

Now you use U: to create project and Git will be fine